# extract archive to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, tar

I want to extract a (git repository) archive to hdfs.

this is what I got so far:

```
git archive --format=tar --remote=[remote] master | \
    tar -xf - --to-stdout | \
    hadoop fs -put - /user/username/archivedir/
```

Unfortunately that just writes everything to one "-" file within the hdfs directory, instead of putting the separate files into the directories and subdirectories they should go to.
I had a look at tar --to-command but it also doesn't seem to do what I want.

Of course I could extract the tar to a temporary local folder and upload it from there, but that doesn't strike me as the most elegant solution.
Is there something simple and obvious that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with multiple files as stdin input.  Looping over the files in the archive worked for me. [Loop over files in tar.gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627951/loop-over-files-in-tar-gz)

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -xvf test.tar | while IFS= read -r f ; do
   echo -e "\n>>> Processing file $f"
   cat "$f" | hadoop fs -put - "data_dir/$f";
done
```