# Loop over files in tar.gz

Tags: bash, unix

I have `files.tar.gz` with a bunch of csv files inside, each having a header. I want to loop over the csv files and process them one at a time. If I just `zcat | tar -xO` them all, then I won't be able to identify the start of each file, and thus its header.

How can I loop over the files in the archive one at a time, and pipe them individually to a processing command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNU `tar` utility can extract individual file from an archive to stdout with

`tar -O -x -z -f archive.tgz file`

Here is a loop that might solve your problem, assuming running `tar` for each file is not prohibitively slow.

```
tar tzf files.tar.gz | while IFS= read -r f ; do 
   echo ">>> Processing file $f"
   tar Oxzf files.tar.gz "$f" | head | cat -n ;
done
```

`command | while IFS= read -r line` is a BASH pattern. Clearing the `IFS` variable is necessary for the code to work correctly when there are spaces in the file names.

Comment: This is the wrong way to iterate over the output of a command; see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).